# How to validate SAML EntitiesDescriptor Signature with Apache Santuario

Tags: java, xml

The aim is to validate a saml EntitiesDescriptor signature using a stux processor to ensure the amount of memory used is low.

I have been using the following code with an [example](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureStAXTest.java) from Apache Santuario without any luck.

Please can someone advise on how to use Apache Santuario with SAML Entity Descriptor files.

SignatureUtils can be found [here](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureUtils.java)

URL url = new URL("http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml");

```
// Validation
List<QName> namesToSign = new ArrayList<QName>();
namesToSign.add(new QName("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata", "EntitiesDescriptor"));

try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
  X509Certificate cert = getCertificate();
  SignatureUtils.verifyUsingStAX(stream, namesToSign, cert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your saml document, the signature is over the root element urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata:EntitiesDescriptor whereas in [Colm O hEigeartaigh's test](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureStAXTest.java), the signature is over a sub element (urn:example:po:PaymentInfo).

I tried to sign the root element urn:example:po:PurchaseOrder in Colm O hEigeartaigh's example and got the same error reported in this [blog comment](http://coheigea.blogspot.fr/2014/03/apache-santuario-xml-security-for-java.html#c4704537526938275646).

I followed Colm O hEigeartaigh's advise and used enveloped signature to sign over the root element in SignatureUtils :

```
for (QName nameToSign : namesToSign) {
        SecurePart securePart = new SecurePart(nameToSign, SecurePart.Modifier.Content);
        String[] transforms = new String[2];
        transforms[0] = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature";
        transforms[1] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
        securePart.setTransforms(transforms);
        properties.addSignaturePart(securePart);
    }
```

and was able to validate signature using `SignatureUtils#verifyUsingStAX`

I then removed the xml signature in your document, signed it using enveloped signature and manage to validate the signature. I therefore recommend you use enveloped signature to sign root element.

Comment: Thank you for the post, but I need to validate the signature of the following document http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml, rather than sign it.